# How to access filename of word document in PHP?

Tags: php, metadata, docx

I have developed some code to read tag information from Word Documents, in PHP. I was wondering how do I read the filenames from a word document and store this in a database table? well I know how to append to a database table but not sure how I can retrieve the filename..

My code:

```
   echo "Keywords : " . $docxmeta->getKeywords() . "<br>"; 
$Keywords = $docxmeta->getKeywords();
?>
```

I have tried to do `$Filename = $docxmeta ->getFileName();` which doesn't work, I'm sure there must be another way if anyone could help me please?

Comment: What's the content of `include("pdf.php");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can scan the directory and it will return an array of file names. Does this help you?

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);


print_r($files1);
?>
```